# Java - Add an element between two elements in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing, addition

i want to add an element between two other elements in an arraylist
like:

```
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
```

Adding an element:

```
Element 1
Element 4 <---- Adding element 4 between 1 and 2.
Element 2
Element 3
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - you want the [overload of `add` that takes an index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,E)). In this case, the index would be 1:

```java
list.add(1, 4); // Index then value
```

Note that adding an element involves copying all existing elements *after* that (so values 2 and 3 in your example), so if you do this a lot with a very large list, it can have performance implications.

Answer (score 3):

Simple as that:

```
myList.add(1, "Element 4");
```

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,E)) documentation for further details.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the add() method of ArrayList to insert an element at any particular index.

Assuming the name of your ArrayList is list, you can add 4 at index 1 in this manner-

`list.add(1, 4);`

The first parameter takes the index and the second parameter takes the value of the element you want to insert.